# How to get different API versions for a System Image in AVD Manager?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have downloaded all the API versions. Here is what my SDK Manager tab looks like.

[image]

But when I try to create a new Virtual device I do not see the option to create Virtual Device other than API 28 and API 23.

### My Virtual Device Configuration Page looks like.

[image]

### This is what I want

[image]

How can I get the multiple options to create Virtual device with different API level (Oreo, Nougat, Pie etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### VPN was the culprit.

I was in the enterprise network and and I was using VPN. I did not realize that VPN was restricting the AVD manager to show the available SDK platform for download.

#### Solution?

**I simply turned off the VPN,  reopened the AVD Manager and it worked.**

I have worked many years in Android Studio but recently I started using VPN. So I was not able to figure out what went wrong. It seems a silly question but hope it helps someone someday!